# Can't find anywhere how to make a search interface widget

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to make a search bar in my app (edit: for the content in the database linked to my app), but every tutorial that I found makes that in the appbar, is there any way to make a widget like google search bar in the app?

Comment: The "Search bar widget" on my device only seems to act like a giant button that takes me to a Google search app

Comment: put the EditText on the CardView

Comment: if your looking for google search bar https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog. they already provided all the information